# LAN Settings disabled in Internet Options. How to enable it?

Tags: lan

I do not know why it got disabled. I didn't do anything relating to disabling it to the best of my knowledge.

How can I enable it?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any program installed that might want to change the proxy settings? That could be a browser for example. I know that chrome will not disable the LAN settings, firefox won't either but maybe there are browsers that will or maybe some other network related software that has something to do with proxy servers did this. If you have Windows 10 go to settings/network and internet/proxy and see if that's accessible.

Comment: Yes. I can set up proxy manually in settings/network and internet/proxy.

Comment: Is `LAN-settings` being reenabled if you set up a proxy? Did you install any software shortly before that button became disabled?

Comment: I can set proxy in settings/network and internet/ proxy , and also through Firefox(options/advanced/network/settings).

Comment: You being able to change the Firefox settings is not helpful, Firefox can only be configured through a group policy, if additional Administrative templates are added.  You need to keep your question limited to your problem with Internet Explorer.

Comment: @SpiderPig no it's not. I didn't install any software.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I enable it?

Modify the group policy that is currently prohibiting you from modifying it.

> In the Group Policy window please navigate to User Configuration ->
>   Administrative Templates ->  Network -> Network Connections and open
>   Prohibit access to properties of a LAN connection.
>
> [image]

You will want to change the value to **Disabled**

> [image]

If you are unable to use the group policy editor (gpedit.msc) then you will have to modify the appropriate registry key.

> Navigate to
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Network
>   Connections` and locate **NC_LanProperties** registry key.
>
> [image]

You will want to change the value of **NC_LanProperties** to **0** if you want to disable the policy.  If you are not an Administrator on the machine and you do not have authorization to make this change, the change will automatically be reverted by your IT Administrator, do not make any changes to your system you are not authorized to make.

Sources:

- [Prohibit access to properties of a LAN 
  connection](http://www.computerstepbystep.com/prohibit-access-to-properties-of-a-lan-connection.html#)
- [Prohibit access to properties of a LAN connection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc975891.aspx)

Comment: I have disabled 'prohibit access to properties of a LAN connection'. But no luck. LAN settings button is still greyed out.

Comment: @HemaChandra - You are using an user in the Administrators user group?  You have verified the registry key in question?  You have also restarted the machine (which is required to refresh the group policy) was left unsaid because I presumed you knew that.  You must disable the policy on the AD server then perform a `gpupdate /force` on the client machine (then reboot the client machine).

Comment: Yes. I am using an user in the Administrators user group. In fact, i have done as per the above instructions under Administrator user.  I have disabled the policy and then changed the registry key to 0. Restarted the laptop. But no luck. Still greyed out.

Comment: AD server? I'm not on office machine.

Comment: @HemaChandra - I made no mention of an AD server in my answer.

Comment: This isn't to anyone particular, but if you are going to issue a downvote to my answer, you really should indicate the reason you are doing so.  I would love to improve this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the bottom of the box: -

Some settings are controlled by your system administrator

Most likely - The LAN settings button has been disabled using group policy. Are you on a domain?

Other possibilities, a program has modified your registry to hide some nefarious action.

Comment: It's my laptop. The result is same even when I login as Administrator. LAN Settings button is greyed out for both user and Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I fixed this by running a [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.com/) scan. It turns out our system was exposed to malware.

Answer (score 2):

I solved deleting all keys inside:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SOFTWARE>POLICIES>INTERNET EXPLORER>CONTROL PANEL

Answer (score 2):

Its possible that the value of the below registry setting is set to 1. Just change to 0 and restart the browser.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel

[image: Registry setting]

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 10 apply these four steps:

1. Type "ncpa.cpl" in search window option
2. Double click on "VPN Connection" option
3. Click on

   > Proxy -> Manual proxy setup -> Use a proxy server ON button.
4. Restart IE Browser

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC9g1.jpg)User should be having administrative rights. 
Following has helped me to enable the greyed out LAN settings 
Run> gpedit.msc > User configuration >Administrative temples  on the right side settings "Prohibiting  to enable/disable LAN connections" right click edit "Enable" and apply the settings.